# Erro ao fazer Linked Server com banco Firebird

Tags: sql-server, firebird, driver, linked-server

Instalei o Firebird 2.5 e o devido driver ODBC no meu computador. Testei a conexão e deu tudo certo, chamei o banco de **DB**. Mas quando crio o linked server no SQL Management Studio 2008, me dá o seguinte erro, número 7303:

> O provedor do OLE DB "MSDASQL" para o servidor vinculado "DB" retornou
>   a mensagem "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] O DSN especificado contém
>   uma incompatibilidade de arquiteturas entre o Driver e o Aplicativo".

Como eu posso resolver esse erro?

Comment: Gustavo estou com o mesmo problema, você conseguiu identificar esse problema ? Se sim, poste qual solução você encontrou.